# Gagliardo Nirenberg Sobolev inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Assume that $f$ satisfies the equality in the Gagliardo Nirenberg Sobolev inequality for the best constant. What can be said about $f$?

Comment: You might be interested in this [nice derivation](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mccann/assignments/477/CorderoNazaretVillani04.pdf) of sharp Gagliardo Nirenberg Sobolev inequalities using mass transport. I'm not sure what heuristic things can be said about $f$ in the general case but the special case of $p=1$ is easy because you get the isoperimetric inequality which says that for a fixed volume $V$, balls have the lowest surface area.

Comment: For $p=2$ it's known that $f $ solves a nonlinear elliptic equation. Try searching "critical wave equation", where these minimizers appear as ground states ( in fact an explicit formula for them is known). For $p $ not 2 I'm not sure what is known.